# Laravel 7: Installing od FTP Server

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, installation

I installed Laravel 7 on my FTP server, but I get this message

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php on line 23
```

When I used localhost everything was fine. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel 7 require PHP >= 7.2.5. Check version installed on server.