# Error when upload laravel project to host

Tags: laravel, host

I have problem when upload laravel project to hosting,

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home2/zainprad/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php on line 23

anyone can help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 7: Installing od FTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374148/laravel-7-installing-od-ftp-server)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 7 require PHP >= 7.2.5. Check version installed on server

already question available please search before post
[Laravel 7: Installing od FTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374148/laravel-7-installing-od-ftp-server)